# What triggers finally throwing an AggregateException in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

When I suspect a `Task`'s `Action` had failed I used to just sit waiting for the `AggregateException`to finally get thrown so I could dig into the `InnerException`. Recently, however, I noticed that by attempting to resize the form which had initiated the failing `Task` I could force the error to throw visibly.

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this? (I hate the "Wrap the call in an try/catch/re-`throw` and put a break point on the re-`throw` technique).
2. I *thought* the `AggregateException` got thrown when the `Task` object itself is garbage collected. Is that true?
3. In light of the answer to #2: Why does resizing trigger the `AggregateException` more immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do this?

You can either use the `Result` property or the `Wait()` function. Both block and if the `Task` fails, they throw the `AggregateException`. Another option, if you want to do something with the exception, is to use `ContinueWith()` with `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`.

> I thought the AggregateException got thrown when the Task object itself is garbage collected. Is that true?

Yes, if the `Exception` of the `Task` is not accessed in any way, it will throw the exception when it's finalized on .Net 4.0. (.Net 4.5 changes that, unhandled exceptions from `Task`s no longer throw when the `Task` is finalized.)

> In light of the answer to #2: Why does resizing trigger the `AggregateException` more immediately?

Most likely because it creates some objects, which causes the garbage collection to run.